# Updating a contact's name programatically in android results in illegalargumentexception in emulator

Tags: java, android, contacts, illegalargumentexception

Before I start, I know I'm using the deprecated API calls in the code to manage the contacts and it is because I'm trying to extend an existing library without having to make too many changes to it. I won't mind changing it but there's too many things there and I'm just experimenting with an idea and don't want to write a whole framework again.

So now coming to the question, I'm trying to update a contact but so far I'm not getting anywhere. I'm able to create and delete the contacts. They all work in the emulator. I'm actually getting an illegalargumentexception: empty values message when I try to update though. The relevant code is below.

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(fullUri);
ContentValues updateValues = new ContentValues();
// updateValues.put(Contacts.People.DISPLAY_NAME, value);
updateValues.put(Contacts.People.NAME, value);
contentResolver.update(uri, updateValues, null, null);
```

and below is my stack trace

```
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:507)
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592):    at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:990)
12-30 00:45:05.819: RpcServer:101(2592):    at com.fun.rpc.SimpleServer$ConnectionThread.run(SimpleServer.java:91)
```

Has anyone seen this problem before? I tried sending the ID as part of the where clause, that didn't work either. Also if I try to update email address the code doesn't throw any errors but the contact's email address doesn't get updated though. But when I try to update the name I get the error as above. Any hints or ideas please? Please let me know if you need more info.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I was late for the party, but my answer is the following.

I met the same error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Empty values
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:165)
at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.update(ContentProviderNative.java:572)
at android.content.ContentResolver.update(ContentResolver.java:1672)
...
```

I encountered the same error when I tried to change the `MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_ID` field.
While the field `MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION` was changed without problems.

As you might guess, the `BUCKET_ID` field serves as a key field for several tables. If you know the theory of database development.
It follows that such **key fields** will not be allowed to be changed.

In your case, such an (protected) field is `Contacts.People.NAME`.

**upd**. From src:

*The bucket id of the image. This is a read-only property that is automatically computed from the DATA column.*